# How to ensure no other thread modifies a ConcurrentDictionary object when iterating through it?

Tags: concurrentdictionary

Here is my scenario:
-I am using ConcurrentDictionary
-Several threads can write to this dictionary
-Now, at the end of every periodic interval, I need to read this whole dictionary and print their values. While enumerating through this dictionary using foreach and printing, I don't want any other thread to modify the contents of the dictionary. ConcurrentDictionary apparently does not lock while reading. So, what is the best approach to follow to ensure that no other thread modifies this concurrent dictionary when I am reading it? Should I just lock on the ConcurrentDictionary object?

Comment: Use a lock or similar mutex. ConcurrentDictionary does *not* mean that sets of operations or atomic: it just means that any *particular* operation will work in a thread-safe manner (or as otherwise detailed). Also, make sure to add an appropriate *language* tag.

Comment: You mean something like lock(concurrentDictionaryObject) or locking on a separate static object?

Comment: Locking on *an* applicable common object - while it is one approach to lock on the ConcurrentDictionary (or other collection object) itself, others (like me) may point out that the lock object should not lock on external types (what if they locked on themselves in their own implementation?) and should be implemented in a hidden fashion (so that only the people who should acquire the lock can). Believe it or not, over-locking (i.e. on everything) can also result in incorrectly function code: and it is no fun to find this out through some obscure side-effect in a production system.

Comment: Now, after my rant, it's still on *you* to come up with what "applicable .. object" means :D (I avoid static variables and methods whenever possible - I'd much prefer a singleton injected.)

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` should, IMHO, have included a method which would yield an `IEnumerable<TKey,TValue>` which would behave as a snapshot of the collection.  Adding an external lock will only work if it is used to arbitrate all actions that change the collection; taking a snapshot wouldn't be cheap, but if a dictionary is used heavily and snapshots are needed seldom, it could be cheaper and easier than using an external lock on all updates.